# labeling data points from two different dataframe columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I want to label my data points from two different dataframe columns ('C' and 'D'). But the annotations are overlapping making it impossible to read properly.

```
x = 'A'
y = 'B'

ax.plot(df[x], df[y], "ro")

df[[x, y, 'C']].apply(lambda x: ax.text(*x), axis=1)
df[[x, y, 'D']].apply(lambda x: ax.text(*x), axis=1)
```

Where in this apply function do i have to change the position? I don't get it.

Comment: Maybe you rather want to create a single annotation, which contains the content of the C and D column? E.g. separated by a line break or a space?

Comment: That was actually a pretty good idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `plt.annotate` to shift the text with respect to the point you want to annotate. This is done using the `textcoords` keyword. Here we might shift the one text by `+3` and the other by `-3` points.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,50, size=(8,4)), columns=list("ABCD"))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.A, df.B, "ro")

f = lambda x, kw: ax.annotate(x[2], xy=(x[0],x[1]), textcoords="offset points", **kw)
g = lambda x: ax.annotate(x[2], xy=(x[0],x[1]), xytext=(2,-5), textcoords="offset points", va="top")
df[["A", "B", 'C']].apply(lambda x: f(x,dict(xytext=(2,3))), axis=1)
df[["A", "B", 'D']].apply(lambda x: f(x,dict(xytext=(2,-3), va="top")), axis=1)

ax.margins(0.1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Z'] = df['C'] + ' ' + df['D'].map(str)
df[[x, y, 'Z']].apply(lambda x: ax.text(*x), axis=1)
```

Combining the two columns did the job quite nice as well. Thanks!